# Unable to test form submission code in unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Hi I am writing unit test case to submit form. I am trying to test form submit below code. Below is my form.

```
 <form *ngIf="formResetToggle" class="form-horizontal" name="scopesEditorForm" #f="ngForm" novalidate
 (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && isScopeValid() ? saveScope() : showErrorAlert('Please enter mandatory fields')">
 <input autofocus type="text" id="scopename" name="scopename"/>
 <input type="submit" id="savescope" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Scope" />
</form>
```

Below is my unit test code.

```
it('add scope', () => {
        let saveScopeButton = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#savescope');
        scopename = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#scopename'));
        scopename.nativeElement.value = "/bmw/v1/s1";
        component.scopeEdit.scopevalue = scopename.name;
        saveScopeButton.click();
        var rows = component.rows;
        expect(rows.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        var isScopeNameAdded = rows.filter(
            scope => scope.scopevalue === 'xcxcx');
        if (isScopeNameAdded.length) {
            console.log('add scope unit test case passed');
        }
        {
            console.log("add scope unit test case failed");
        }
    });
```

Whenever the above code executes, function showErrorAlert gets executed and saveScope function not executing. Can someone help me to make this works? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can refer form in your component as below.

```
@ViewChild('f')
scopeform: NgForm;
```

then We can set field value as  `component.scopeform.form.controls.scopename.setValue('/bmw/v1/s1');`

Now your form validity will be true. You can test as below.

```
component.scopeform.form.valid
```

or

```
component.scopeform.form.status
```